# Deprecation of v1.0 of the API - What do I change to my existing code?

Tags: android, twitter

I am new to android development and learning. I'm creating an app which stores favorite twitter searches as tags which are clicked on and opened with. In my `strings.xml` I defined one of the tags as: `<string name="searchURL">http://search.twitter.com/search?q=</string>`

When I use the `http://search.twitter.com/search?q=` URL, I'am introduced to:

The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

I was wondering, what changes I should make to migrate to new version. Is it a simple change in the searchURL ?

Answer (score 0):

from the link you sent:

> At this time, all authentication requires user context, but in the
>   coming weeks we'll be pushing out support for a form of authentication
>   not requiring a user context.

I think that perfectly answer your question, isn't it?

Comment: still not convinced what changes to make to go ahead with query on the app :(

Comment: There is nothing to change, this won't work anymore till they release something else. Period.